# There is a unique binary relation $<$ which turn the integral domain $(\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ into an ordered integral domain.

Tags: solution-verification, integers, integral-domain

**Axioms for order relation:**

- $x \not\lt x$
- $[x \lt y \land y \lt z] \Rightarrow x \lt z$
- $[x \lt y \lor x = y \lor y \lt x]$
- $x \lt y \Rightarrow x+z \lt y+z$
- $[x <y \land 0 < z] \Rightarrow x\times z < y \times z$

**Question**:
We have that $(\mathbb{Z}, +, \times, <)$ is the ordered integral domain of integers with the usual order relation defined as $x<y \Leftrightarrow y-x \in Z^+$, we must show that if $(\mathbb{Z}, +, \times, <')$ is an ordered integral domain too, then $<'$ is identical with $<$.

Here is my short atempt:

$$(x<y) \Leftrightarrow (0 <y-x) \Leftrightarrow (y-x \in Z^+) \Leftrightarrow (0 <' y-x) \Leftrightarrow (x<'y)$$

Since $Z^+$ is unique and the order relation on integral domain should give $0<x$ for any positive $x$, I tried this approach after failing in all other paths, some of my other ideas was to assume $<$ and $<'$ as ordering relations satisfying the axioms for ordering and then trying to reach a contradiction if the relations are not identical, but I got stucked.

My atempt is correct?

Comment: Why do you think $(x-y\in Z^+)\iff (0<'y-x)$? $Z^+$ is not mentioned in the order axioms

Comment: I dont mention this on the question but, the book give as a definition that $x$ is positive is defined by the order relation as follows "$x$ is positive $\Leftrightarrow 0<x$", then I assumed that if $<'$ denotes a order relation then $0<'x$ is equivalent to $x \in Z^+$.

Since I cant give a better motivation to this, I think this is not a valid at all.

Comment: Strictly speaking, such definitions should read "$x$ is $<$-positive $\Leftrightarrow \ldots$", and only after exercises like this, we can be sure that simplifying the language does not introduce ambiguity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to prove $1>0$ since this would imply that $x>0>-x$ for $x\in Z^+$, using $1>0$ implies $2>1$ implies ... implies $x>x-1$ and then using the second axiom, while for the other direction we get $1+(-1)>0+(-1)$ using the fourth axiom again.
Since 1 is not 0 in an integral domain, we have that $1>0\vee 1<0$ and if $1<0$, using the fourth axiom, we get that $-1>0$ and using the last axiom we get $0<-1\wedge 0<-1\Rightarrow 0<1$ which is a contradiction. So $1>0$ and we are done.

EDIT: Showing the explicit induction.

Basis for $x=1$ is trivial since we showed $0<1$.

Let $x\in Z^+$ s.t. $x>1$, then $x-1\in Z^+$. Let us assume $x-1>0$ and show that $x>0$: Indeed, we get
$$x=(x-1)+1>^*0+1=1>0$$ where we used the fourth axiom in the starred inequality, and $1>0$ in the last inequality. We finish by using transitivity (2nd axiom) and concluding that $x>0$.

Comment: Using $0<x$ and applying Axiom 5, we got $[x<0 \land x <0]\Rightarrow 0 < x^2$, and if $x<0$, applying Axiom 4 with $-x$ we got $x<0 \Rightarrow x-x < 0-x$ that is $0<-x$, than using Axiom 5 again, $[0<-x \land 0<-x] \Rightarrow 0 < -x \times -x$ then again $0 < x^2$, it shows that $x \neq 0 \Rightarrow 0<x^2$.

Since $0 \neq 1$ we already have $0<1^2$ that is $0<1$, it follows direct from these axioms, thus the assumption you did is a direct contradiction, I cant see how can I use this to show that $<$ and $<'$ must be identical.

Comment: Indeed, $1$ is a square, hence $0<'1$ holds also for the order $<'$. In $Z^+$, we can use induction, so let's do it to prove $0<'n$ for all $n\in Z^+$ (using transitivity and the basic result $0<1$. Then $-n=0+(-n)<n+(-n)=0$ for all $n\in Z^+$ and as $\Bbb Z=(-Z^+)\cup \{0\}\cup Z^+$, we now have $a\in Z^+\Leftrightarrow 0<'a$, which gives us the central step in your (then successfull) short attempt.

Comment: Thanks @HagenvonEitzen I completly forgot about induction during my atempts, after reading reading about integer as equivalence classes for some pages I dont manged to remeber It have a completle Peano System embbed which in fact is $Z^+$, I appreciate the help.

If you accept, I just want nl1992 add this induction part explicitely to his anwer then I will accept.

Comment: I Think he just used induction as "..." I just dont get it during the first read, but in any case thanks you both!

Comment: @Paulo Henrique L.Amorim I added the explicit induction in the answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer, Thanks for adding the information.